# ScrollView error even though it has one child

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add a ScrollView to my layout as the root view but I'm getting a "ScrollView can host only one direct child" error. I don't understand why I'm getting this error because my layout does have one child. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong here? I've tried everything but nothing seems to work. Here's my layout.

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/ic_back_back"
     tools:context=".login.LoginFragment">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="24dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:labelFor="@id/editTextTextPersonName6"
                android:text="@string/username"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonClientPassword"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:labelFor="@id/editTextTextPersonName6"
                android:text="@string/password"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonClientName"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonClientName"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonClientName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonClientName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:autofillHints=""
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/type_username"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:padding="6sp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:autofillHints=""
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/type_password"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="6sp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonClientPassword"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonClientPassword"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonClientPassword" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonLoginButtonFragmentActivity"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="59dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="@string/login"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName6"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName6" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sisi_logo"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try to replace your top-level Constraint with Linear layout.

Comment: Tried it, same error.

Comment: @DavidWekesa Can you repost your layout. It looks like there are some missing parts. According to current posted layout you don't close ScrollView.

Comment: Edited the post. It should be visible now.

Comment: it works fine while check in my xml

Comment: invalidate cache/restart it then you use it.

Comment: I also tried your layout and it works without an error. You can try also what Adnan haider suggested. Because of curiosity I want to ask why you want to add ScrollView to this layout? In my opinion this layout doesn't need a ScrollView also CardView is scrollable and your all components are inside CardView.

Comment: I've tried invalidating cache and restarting, didn't work. I added a ScrollView to make the password EditText reachable by scrolling when it's covered by the keyboard. I don't understand why it's working for you guys, maybe its a problem with my Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

add in scroll view

```
        android:fillViewport="true"
```

and change cardview

```
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
```